# Bree regular font installed but not shown in website

Tags: css, fonts

Hy guys, I've installed Bree Regular font from this site: http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Bree-Regular. When I try to use it, the text doesn't change:

```
.font{ font-family: "Bree Rg"; }
```

How can I fix it?

**EDIT :** this is the error I get when I use `format("opentype")`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c9h5.png)

Comment: Have you included the font in your html/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) at the beginning of your `CSS` stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Bree Rg";
    src: url("path/to/your/font/folder/Bree_Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, even if I had to drop format("opentype") cause it gave an error

Comment: Actually format is just an indication for the browser, it is not mandatory. But according to the documentation, it should work. Maybe you have an old browser? Anyway, can you accept this answer by clicking on the V. It may help other people.

Comment: No I'm using the latest stable Chrome's version

Comment: So, the error occurs because you didn't put your URL path in quotes like I did. This cause the interpreter to read the URL path as `path/to/your/font/folder/Bree_Regular.otf) format(opentype` instead of just `path/to/your/font/folder/Bree_Regular.otf`.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in **Head** in your **html** file:-

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree Regular' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Then try.

Comment: Google fonts doesn't include Bree Regular font, but Bree Serif

Comment: Okay you may add **Bree Serif**. Instead of **Bree Regular**.